# Approximate string matching with a provided reference list in Python

Tags: python, text, match

I would like to find the most frequently occurring approximate match in a long string WITH A CONDITION that the word is also from a provided list.

Example:

```
# provided list 
>> jobskill = ["scrum", "customer experience improvement", "python"]

# long string 
>> jobtext = ["We are looking for Graduates in our Customer Experience department in Swindon, you will be responsible for improving customer experience and will also be working with the digital team. Send in your application by 31st December 2018", 
"If you are ScrumMaster at the top of your game with ability to communicate inspire and take people with you then there could not be a better time, we are the pioneer in digital relationship banking, and we are currently lacking talent in our Scrum team, if you are passionate about Scrum, apply to our Scrum team, knowledge with python is a plus!"]

# write a function that returns most frequent approximate match
>> mostfrequent(input = jobtext, lookup = jobskill)
# desired_output: {"customer experience improvement, "scrum"}
```

Appreciate any form of help, thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you absolutely have no idea, you can start bylooping over both lists, and then compare the strings.

Comment: There is no **customer experience improvement** in your long string

Comment: @HenryYik I've tried process.extractOne from the fuzzywuzzy library, but it does not give the best match. Do you mind showing how the loop can get the result?

Comment: @ThatBird 'customer experience' is the most frequently occuring match to 'customer experience improvement', thats why I was hoping the function would return approximate match instead of exact match.

Answer (score 0):

## Using fuzzywuzzy

```
from collections import defaultdict
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# provided list
jobskill = ["scrum", "customer experience improvement", "python"]

# long string
jobtext = [
    "We are looking for Graduates in our Customer Experience department in Swindon, you will be responsible for improving customer experience and will also be working with the digital team. Send in your application by 31st December 2018",
    "If you are ScrumMaster at the top of your game with ability to communicate inspire and take people with you then there could not be a better time, we are the pioneer in digital relationship banking, and we are currently lacking talent in our Scrum team, if you are passionate about Scrum, apply to our Scrum team, knowledge with python is a plus!",
]


def k_most_frequent(k, text, queries, threshold=70):
    """Return k most frequent queries using fuzzywuzzy to match."""

    frequency = defaultdict(int)
    text = " ".join(text).split()
    for query in queries:
        for window in range(len(query.split()) + 1):
            frequency[query] += sum(
                [
                    fuzz.ratio(query, " ".join(text[i : i + window])) > threshold
                    for i in range(len(text))
                ]
            )

    return sorted(frequency.keys(), key=frequency.get, reverse=True)[:k]


print(k_most_frequent(2, jobtext, jobskill))

# output: ["customer experience improvement, "scrum"]
```